# Resampling procedure for unequal sampling units

Tags: r, biostatistics, resampling, lme4-nlme

I’d like to know if the diversity of waterbirds affect zooplankton diversity in natural temporary pools over two seasonal periods (wet and dry). I’ve sampled zooplankton in 38 10x15 cm plots on the pool’s shore sediment (in the same place where birds usually) in both seasonal periods. I used a model of bird feet and simulated them walking on the sediment of each plot. Then, I washed the bird feet (of each plot separately) into containers with filtered water. The zooplankton that emerged from this water were identified.

Unfortunately, I was not able to collect birds at the same plot (and at the same time) that I simulated their footprint. Rather, I’ve made 38 samples (during 9 months immediately after each seasonal period) of bird communities (direct observation on each pool).

Thus, I do not believe that can use any classic model (such as anova designs) because birds and zooplankton were not collected at the same sampling unit. To do this, I thought to randomly select 10 plots of each combination of zooplankton sampling, that is: 10 samples from pool 1/wet season, 10 from pool 1/dry season, 10 from pool 2/wet season and 10 from pool 2/dry season. I did the same with bird samples, selecting 10 samples by pool and season combination. Then, we run a lme model using species richness of birds (independent variable) and zooplankton (dependent variable), and season as independent variable. The variables were nested in pool. I repeated (for loop) this procedure 1000 times and calculated the number of times that the model was significant (p < 0.05) and the accompanying F values (for bird richness and season effects).

I’d like to hear from you if this procedure make any sense. Please, see below a reproducible example. Thank you very much!

Note: I’m pretty sure that the for loop could be shorter ;)

### required packages

```
library(nlme)
```

### zooplankton table

```
ric.zoo <- rnorm(120, 20, 2)
pool <- factor(rep(c("pool1", "pool2"), 60))
```

season <- factor(rep(rep(c("dry", "wet"), each=30), 2))
    tab <- data.frame(pool, season, ric.zoo)

### birds table

```
ric.bird <- rnorm(76, 10, 2)
pool_b <- factor(rep(c("pool1", "pool2"), 38))
season_b <- factor(rep(rep(c("dry", "wet"), each=19), 2))
tab_b <- data.frame(pool=pool_b, season=season_b, ric.bird)
```

### Dataset to be used in for loops

```
bird.p.val <- numeric()
season.p.val <- numeric()
bird.f <- numeric()
season.f <- numeric()
pool.sort <- rep(c("pool1", "pool2"), each=20)
season.sort <- rep(rep(c("wet", "dry"), each=10), 2)
factor.sort <- data.frame(pool=pool.sort, season=season.sort)
nreps <- 1000
```

### Resampling procedure for choose zooplankton and bird samples to use in LME

```
for(i in 1:nreps){
subset1 <- subset(tab, pool=="pool1"&season=="wet")
subsample1 <- subset1[sample(nrow(subset1), 10),][,3]
subset2 <- subset(tab, pool=="pool1"&season=="dry")
subsample2 <- subset2[sample(nrow(subset2), 10),][,3]
subset3 <- subset(tab, pool=="pool2"&season=="wet")
subsample3 <- subset3[sample(nrow(subset3), 10),][,3]
subset4 <- subset(tab, pool=="pool2"&season=="dry")
subsample4 <- subset4[sample(nrow(subset4), 10),][,3]
subbird1 <- subset(tab_b, pool=="pool1"&season=="wet")
subsbird1 <- subbird1[sample(nrow(subbird1), 10),][,3]
subbird2 <- subset(tab_b, pool=="pool1"&season=="dry")
subsbird2 <- subbird2[sample(nrow(subbird2), 10),][,3]
subbird3 <- subset(tab_b, pool=="pool2"&season=="wet")
subsbird3 <- subbird3[sample(nrow(subbird3), 10),][,3]
subbird4 <- subset(tab_b, pool=="pool2"&season=="dry")
subsbird4 <- subbird4[sample(nrow(subbird4), 10),][,3]
ric.sort.zoo <- c(subsample1, subsample2, subsample3, subsample4)
ric.sort.birds <- c(subsbird1, subsbird2, subsbird3, subsbird4)
df40 <- data.frame(ric.zoo=ric.sort.zoo, ric.bird=ric.sort.birds,      factor.sort)
lm.nested <- lme(ric.zoo~ric.bird+season, random=~1|pool, data=df40,  method="REML") # MODEL
mod <- anova.lme(lm.nested, type="sequential", adjustSigma = FALSE) 
bird.p.val[i] <- mod$"p-value"[2]
season.p.val[i] <- mod$"p-value"[3] 
bird.f[i] <- mod$"F-value"[2]
season.f[i] <- mod$"F-value"[3]
}

sum(bird.p.val<0.05 )/nreps
sum(season.p.val<0.05)/nreps
```